# Why the accuracy decreased with more data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When working with a random forest model, it is surprising that the cross-validation score on the training dataset is much higher than the score on the whole dataset.

Here is the code:

```
X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
cv_score1 = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=3).mean()
print('CV score for the training data is : {:.3f}'.format(cv_score1))
cv_score2 = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=3).mean()
print('CV score for all data is : {:.3f}'.format(cv_score2))
```

The first score is 0.887 while the second score is 0.645.
The trend is the same with a linear support vector machine model.
Is this normal? Or I have done something wrong? How can I fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Seems that the trained model has little external validity, meaning that it performs poorly on the test/holdout set. What result do you get when you predict only the test/holdout set?

Comment: The holdout score is close to the CV score. Around 0.87 for the training set.

Comment: I have figured it out. The difference between the training set and the whole dataset is that the training set has been shuffled during the train test splitting. Get a similar score on the whole dataset after shuffling the data. I have assumed that the data will be shuffled anyway during the cross-validation but seemed it is not.